# jquery autocomplete with django

Tags: search, jquery-autocomplete, django-haystack

I cant find any examples of client side auto complete with drop down search results and django haystack. I have looked into django-selectable but it dosen't use text fields. how to integrate jquery auto complete with django haystack

```
    @login_required
def autocomplete(request):
    if 'term' in request.GET:
        people = Person.objects.filter(
            first_name__contains=request.GET['term']
        )[:10]
        print people.count()
    return HttpResponse( simplejson.dumps( [ people.first_name for person in people ] ) )
```

I am for some reason getting a javascript error in google inspect element on debug mode:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was supposed to be person.first_name and not people